# my page always redirects me to my server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, redirect

I'm trying to make a redirection to other page (for example google) but it doesn't work. This is the code:

```js
function algo(a) {
  $.get("links/privado/verlink.php?" + a, function(data, status) {
    document.getElementById("algunacosa").href = data;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="algunacosa">Ir al link</a>
<button onclick="algo">Retrive link</button>
```

if the response is: http://google.com it redirects me to http://mrvikxd.ddns.net/m/http://google.com and appears an 403 error

Edit: I've seen the code on the Google Chrome development console and the href of `<a id="algunacosa">` is `href="http://google.com"`. I don't know why it doesn't go to Google.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I can only assume that `links/privado/verlink.php` is not returning what you think it is returning.

Comment: May you share exactly what you are getting from server in `data`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed. verlink.php was in UTF-8 BOM and it was producing the \uffef character what is not visible but enought to confuse the browser

Answer (score 0):

Using the `rel` attribute on your anchor tag, you should be able to force the link to lead to an external site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

```
<a id="algunacosa" rel="external">Ir al link</a>
```